# Azure active directory with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, restful-authentication

I am trying to use azure active directory for my spring boot based REST FUL  webservice .

I went through lot of document and got confused which one is correct way of securing my restful service .

My rest ful service will be consumed by internal and external entity both .

Comment: What problem did you encounter?

Comment: Are you still facing any issue here?